# When calling a callback function with a conditional type, typescript requires passing a parameter with an intersection of types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

There is a function that takes a certain set of arguments. In particular, a callback function that takes as an argument an object or an array of objects that depends on another isArray parameter.

I'm trying to make an addiction.

```
type Option = {
  name: string
  value: string
> }

type FunctionProps<IsArray extends boolean | undefined> = {
  isArray?: IsArray
  callback: IsArray extends false
>     ? (options: Option) => void
>     : (options: option[]) => void
> }

const func = <T extends boolean | undefined = false>({isArray, callback}: FunctionProps<T>) => {
  const options: Option[] = /* */
  const currentOption: Option = /* */

  if (isArray) {
    callback(options)  // Argument of type 'Option[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Option & Option[]'.
  else {
    callback(currentOption)  // Argument of type 'Option' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Option & Option[]'.
>   }
> }
```

When calling func, everything works as it should, but when calling callback inside func, typescript wants to get the intersection of the types `Option & Option[]` as an argument. I can explicitly specify the type when calling `callback(value as Option & Option[])`, but this makes it difficult to understand, and it is not clear what eventually happens inside.
Is it possible to define the type more clearly inside? P.S. If I declare the function type like this, nothing will change

```
type FunctionProps = {
  isArray: false
  callback: (options: Option) => void
} | {
  isArray: true
  callback: (options: Option[]) => void
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Narrowing `callback` based on `isArray` would require a discriminated union `FunctionProps` is not a discriminated union so TS will not be able to follow the relationship between the property types.

IN this case a better option is to make `FunctionProps` a discriminated union and not use a type parameter:

```
type FunctionProps = {
    isArray?: false
    callback: (options: Option) => void
} | {
    isArray: true
    callback: (options: Option[]) => void
}

const func =({ isArray, callback }: FunctionProps) => {
    const options: Option[] = null!
    const currentOption: Option = null!;

    if (isArray) {
        callback(options)  
    } else {
        callback(currentOption)  
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7KBeKBvAUFfUKAhgLYQBcUAzsAE4IoDmeBAbkQDYCuF1dDzAL44coSFABiXFAGNEqAAq0kYKhmwt8CKgEFatIiAD8lAGacqETVBmcOAIyIyA1pQAUK+SiqU4XgJQYAHxQrEgIACY4glAAPhoEUNp6BiCUdDzWthwOTq5QHvDI3r5FqADaALqB6CFhkdEiMqg0UKbSMhhuWEm6+oYANDZ2ji5QgpRSsl5KKlQ1IbiJzd7AUJ7FPrBlKFXqKFw5AIRZLWsyXPoQKMB+xaVe+4ccRwDcIokIpgXJ-SCBS0SBGyuRchS883w1hiEA4lgSQPwINGzjcFyuNzuqECUGh0SAA)